# How to make Section ListView Header unclickable?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-listview

I have a section listview and I have a Row and Header. Header show the month and year whereby Row Shows the profit and stuffs. I have created a dialog box for the Row but whenever i click the Header it prompts me error. How do I make the Header Unclickable ?

My Adapter Class

```
public class TransactionAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<Object> transactions;
    Context c;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    static final int ROW = 0;
    static final int HEADER = 1;

    public TransactionAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Object> transactions){
        this.c = c;
        this.transactions = transactions;
    }

    //Get size of the Transaction ArrayList
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return transactions.size();
    }

    //Get single transaction from the Transaction ArrayList
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return transactions.get(position);
    }

    //Get Single transaction identifier from the Transaction ArrayList
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position){
        //Check the current transaction is Transaction
        if(getItem(position) instanceof ProfitTransactions){
            return ROW;
        }
        return HEADER;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount(){
        return 2;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        //Type of View which is ROW(0) or HEADER(1)
        int type = getItemViewType(position);

        //If there is no View create it,
        if (convertView == null) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            switch (type) {
                case ROW:
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_transaction_items, null);
                    break;
                case HEADER:
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_transaction_header, null);
                    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(220,220,220));

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        switch (type){
            case ROW:
                ProfitTransactions transaction = (ProfitTransactions)getItem(position);

                TextView tvDay = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.day);
                TextView tvTID = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tID);
                TextView tvTotalPrice = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.totalPrice);
                TextView tvTimeOrder = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTime);

                Log.d("transadapter","-----Test: " + Integer.parseInt(transaction.getDayOfOrder()));
                tvDay.setText(transaction.getDayOfOrder()+ getDayNumberSuffix(Integer.parseInt(transaction.getDayOfOrder())));
                tvTID.setText("TID: " + transaction.gettId());
                tvTotalPrice.setText("+$"+String.format("%.2f", transaction.getTotalPrice()));
                tvTimeOrder.setText("At: " + transaction.getTimeOfOrder());
                break;
            case HEADER:
                String header = (String)getItem(position);
                // from string to date

                SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yyyy");
                Date date = null;
                try {
                    date = inputFormat.parse(header);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // from date to string
                SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM yyyy");
                String dateTime = outputFormat.format(date);


                TextView tvMonthYear = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvHeaderMonthYear);
                tvMonthYear.setText(dateTime);

                default:
                    break;
        }

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ProfitTransactions transaction = (ProfitTransactions)getItem(position);
                //Create the Dialog Box
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);

                //Put message in the Dialog Box
                builder.setMessage("Name: " + transaction.getName() + "\n" +
                        "Price: " + transaction.getPrice() + "\n" +
                        "Quantity: " + transaction.getQuantity() + "\n" +
                        "Total Price: " + transaction.getTotalPrice() + "\n"
                )

                        //If user click Yes
                        .setPositiveButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {



                            }
                        });



                //Show the dialog after creating
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();
            }
        });

        return convertView;

    }

}
```

The expected result I want is I want the Header which contains the Month and Year to be unclickable and will not respond anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the getViewMethod use this

```
case HEADER:
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_transaction_header, null);
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(220,220,220));
                convertView.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: @jun It fixes your immediate bug, but your logic is still wrong. 
You don't want to register clickListeners on HEADER items to begin with. 
Only set them on ROW items, i.e. pull your convertView.setOnClickListener in the ROW branch of your switch statement

Answer (score 0):

The same way you are making decisions on what to inflate and how to fill your views in `getView` method, you could set the `OnClickListener` to null in the desired type. You could use the `setClickable` method also.

Answer (score 0):

Before the convertView.setOnClickListener, add the if logic to check whether the convertView is a header or a row which is selected! like-

```
if(!convertView.equals("HEADER"))
{
your onClick listener.....
}
else
{
what you want to do if its headerview being the view selected...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're registering the click listener on every View. 
You only want to assign it to rows, not headers, because in the handler you are trying to access fields on the `ProcessTransaction` which are only present on rows.

So just pull your click listener code into the `ROW` branch of your switch.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    //Type of View which is ROW(0) or HEADER(1)
    int type = getItemViewType(position);

    //If there is no View create it,
    if (convertView == null) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        switch (type) {
            case ROW:
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_transaction_items, null);
                break;
            case HEADER:
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_transaction_header, null);
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(220,220,220));

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    switch (type){
        case ROW:
            ProfitTransactions transaction = (ProfitTransactions)getItem(position);

            TextView tvDay = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.day);
            TextView tvTID = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tID);
            TextView tvTotalPrice = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.totalPrice);
            TextView tvTimeOrder = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTime);

            Log.d("transadapter","-----Test: " + Integer.parseInt(transaction.getDayOfOrder()));
            tvDay.setText(transaction.getDayOfOrder()+ getDayNumberSuffix(Integer.parseInt(transaction.getDayOfOrder())));
            tvTID.setText("TID: " + transaction.gettId());
            tvTotalPrice.setText("+$"+String.format("%.2f", transaction.getTotalPrice()));
            tvTimeOrder.setText("At: " + transaction.getTimeOfOrder());

            convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

            ProfitTransactions transaction = (ProfitTransactions)getItem(position);
            //Create the Dialog Box
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);

            //Put message in the Dialog Box
            builder.setMessage("Name: " + transaction.getName() + "\n" +
                    "Price: " + transaction.getPrice() + "\n" +
                    "Quantity: " + transaction.getQuantity() + "\n" +
                    "Total Price: " + transaction.getTotalPrice() + "\n"
            )

                    //If user click Yes
                    .setPositiveButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {



                        }
                    });



            //Show the dialog after creating
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();
        }
    });
            break;
        case HEADER:
            String header = (String)getItem(position);
            // from string to date

            SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yyyy");
            Date date = null;
            try {
                date = inputFormat.parse(header);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // from date to string
            SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM yyyy");
            String dateTime = outputFormat.format(date);


            TextView tvMonthYear = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvHeaderMonthYear);
            tvMonthYear.setText(dateTime);

            default:
                break;
    }

    return convertView;

}
```